# My heroku java app (telegram bot) won't compile at launch

Tags: java, maven, heroku, telegram-bot

The following error occurred while loading my telegram bot written in Java (Maven).

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
-----> Executing Maven
       $ mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [WARNING] 
       [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.example:GesualdoBot:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
       [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 12, column 21
       [WARNING] 
       [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
       [WARNING] 
       [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
       [WARNING] 
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] ----------------------< org.example:GesualdoBot >-----------------------
       [INFO] Building GesualdoBot 1.0-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ GesualdoBot ---
       [INFO] Deleting /tmp/build_86eafd8379099658ed8301a1e005ecb8/target
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ GesualdoBot ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ GesualdoBot ---
       [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_86eafd8379099658ed8301a1e005ecb8/src/main/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ GesualdoBot ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /tmp/build_86eafd8379099658ed8301a1e005ecb8/target/classes
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  2.370 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-27T18:45:46Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project GesualdoBot: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem? I think the first warning is detected because in my pom.xml file I have not specified a version for maven-compiler-plugin; does anyone know how do i see the current version i am using?

Comment: The error links to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException, which explains this isn't Maven failing at something, but one of your plugins. At the top of the error report, it even says "'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 12, column 21" so you probably want to fix that?

Comment: I fixed this problem by adding <version> 3.1 </version> in my pom.xml file. The strange thing that this error no longer appears locally on my computer if I run "mvn compile" but if I load the whole project on heroku it gives me the same errors as before. Maybe the problem isn't with maven-compiler-plugin? this is my pom.xml file https://pastebin.com/b5zqd1r2

Comment: Remember to put [all details in your post](/help/how-to-ask): links expire, questions on SO do _not_, so slim down the content of that pom file to something appropriate to putting in your post, and then add that to your post. If you suspect the problem might be heroku then you're going to have to explain your heroku settings to folks (and possibly even _ask heroku_ as well, not just hope to get an answer here).